# <built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error

Tags: python, opencv

```
    def image_descriptors(file):
      img = cv2.imread(file,0)
      img = cv2.resize(img, (256, 256))
      _ , descriptors = cv2.SIFT().detectAndCompute(img, None)
   return descriptors
   def folder_descriptors(folder):
     cv_img=[]
     for img in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
         n=cv2.imread(img)
         cv_img.append(n)
   print("Calculating descriptos. Number of images is", len(cv_img))
   return np.concatenate([image_descriptors(file) for file in cv_img])
```

I am getting the following in output screen:
Calculating descriptos. Number of images is 274
SystemError:  returned NULL without setting an error

Answer (score 0):

`Path.glob` return list of `Path` object (`WindowsPath` in windows or `PosixPath` in linux). and `cv2.imread` expect *string*.

you can get string of path from `Path` object using `str` class (`str(path_object)`) or build in magic method from `Path` object (`path_object.__str__()`)

```
def image_descriptors(file):
  img = cv2.imread(file,0)
  img = cv2.resize(img, (256, 256))
  _ , descriptors = cv2.SIFT().detectAndCompute(img, None)
  return descriptors
def folder_descriptors(folder):
  cv_img=[]
  for img in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
     # convert `Path` object to string
     n=cv2.imread(str(img))
     cv_img.append(n)
  print("Calculating descriptos. Number of images is", len(cv_img))
  return np.concatenate([image_descriptors(file) for file in cv_img])
```